# Should an edit that removes redundant code be approved?

Tags: discussion, edits, answers, rejected-edits

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47301248/2718801) answer, the last selector (`ul li a:hover { color: white; }`) is redundant, as its values match what would be provided for `ul li a { color: inherit; }`. Try removing the last selector for yourself to verify this is correct.

I made a suggested edit, removing that selector with the comment "remove redundant code), which was rejected. If you read the comments, I point out that "the ul li a:hover selector is redundant in this, as it's still using the same color." The original answerer(?) responded that "It should go without saying, so the edit would not be necessary. ... it doesn't improve the answer in any way".

Maybe it's just me, but how does removing redundant code not improve an answer, especially if "it should go without saying"? To me, this makes no sense.

It's worth noting that this did *not* go through the queue, and was presumably the poster that rejected the edit.

Seeking thoughts on whether this should have been approved, as it prevents people from using redundant code.

Comment: @KevinB Yes, as the *intent* is to provide for inheriting the color. Setting the color explicitly (in the final selector) defeats that purpose.

Comment: No I'm not? The outcome is the same - the link text will be white whenever the `<li>` is hovered.

Comment: The problem there is you use `//` to separate the sections. CSS only has block-style comments :)

Comment: Yeah, I initially only tested it in an "answer" that wasn't posted.

Comment: i wouldn't be against such an edit, but... the owner of the answer isn't wrong for rejecting it, it's their answer after all.

Comment: I totally get that. The purpose of my edit was just to remove (literally) useless code, while still preserving the intent.

Comment: It might be better to start out with adding comments to the answer.

Comment: Or you could just post an answer yourself, saying something like: Whilst the answer from X does provide a solution it contains redundant code, see my code for a cleaner solution.

Comment: @Luuklag: No, I'd advice against that. If all you're changing is to remove 3 lines of code, a comment saying _"those lines don't do anything"_ is plenty. Don't duplicate the rest of the answer.

Comment: That CSS might be redundant for this one example here on Stack Overflow, but *it's not hurting anything*, and may actually have some relevance once the OP moves the corrected CSS back into their full project. Some people just like to be explicit. I would have rejected this edit as well.

Answer (score 1):

Subjective though in most cases, no.

In most cases only the *relevant* code is provided to help people providing an answer stay focused.

If *all* of the code is provided and (in the case of CSS) this rule was not clearly an exception to an earlier rule *then* yes.

If you're not certain don't blindly edit. Many of my own questions have been edited in to something entirely different and then two seconds later marked as a duplicate against (the original) unrelated question(s). It is always better to do fewer things decisively than many things foolishly.